# WordPress: Ajax response overwrites the whole page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I recently started on WordPress and I did a small tutorial on Ajax.

Currently, I am trying to retrieve the content of a post and then display them on the same page in another div (which has been created using short-codes).  Everything is working except that the response is displayed over the whole page and is not displayed in the selected div - thus clearing the other contents.

Please find below snippets of the code I wrote:

```
 ////CREATING SHORT CODES
        public function posts_callback($atts = null, $content = null) {
        $args = array("post_type" => "post", "orderby" => "date", "order" => "DESC", "post_status" => "publish");
        $posts = new WP_Query($args);
        ?>
        <div style ="text-align: center" >
            <?php
            if ($posts->have_posts()):
                while ($posts->have_posts()):
                    $posts->the_post();
                    $link = admin_url('admin-ajax.php?action=post_content&post_id='.get_the_ID());
                    ?>
                    <div id="posts_callback_div" style="display: inline-block; width: 300px; border-color: #333; border-style: solid; border-width: 2px; margin-top: 15px;">        
                        <a class='short_code_link' data-post-id='<?php echo get_the_ID() ?>' href='<?php echo $link ?>' >
                            <?php echo get_the_title(); ?>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <?php
                endwhile;
            else:
                echo "";
                die();
            endif;
            ?>
        </div>
        <?php
    }

    public function custom_container_shortCode() {
        ?>
        <div class="custom_container" id="custom_container"  style="width: 300px; border-color: #333; border-style: solid; border-width: 2px; margin-top: 15px;">
            Hi, if you can still see me then the ajax is not working!
        </div>
        <?php
    }
```

//JQUERY PART

```
(function ($) {
    'use strict';
    $(".short_code_link").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        postID = jQuery(this).attr("data-post-id");
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: myAjax.ajaxurl,
           // dataType: "html",
            cache: false,
            data: {
                action: "post_content",
                post_id: postID,
            },
            success: function (response) {
                jQuery("#custom_container").html(response);
            },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert("Status: " + textStatus);
                alert("Error: " + errorThrown);
            }
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

//PHP Handlers

```
//CREATING AJAX API TO RETRIEVE POST CONTENT
public function post_content() {
    $post_id        = $_GET["post_id"];
    $content_post   = get_post($post_id);
    $content        = $content_post->post_content;
    $content        = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
    $content        = str_replace(']]>', ']]$gt', $content);
    echo $content;
    die();
}
```

Can you please point out what I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 3):

You make an asynchronous call to the server and return some `html`. Upon success, you are replacing all the contents of the element with `id="custom_container"` with whatever was returned from server.

Here's the outlined function which does that:

```
       ...
       success: function (response) {
            jQuery("#custom_container").html(response);
        },
       ...
```

You probably want to replace `#custom_container` with another selector, depending on where you want to place the received `html`.

Please note that the newly created `html` will not be initialized. If you have any scripts binding events/behaviour to elements on page load, you will need to add the events/behavior to your newly added `html` inside the `success` function outlined above or you will need to use generic bindings at page load.

Comment: Thanks. I only want to replace the content in the #custom_container.  But instead the whole page is being replaced by the response and I can't understand why.  Hence my question to understand why this is happening.

Can you please eleborate on the events/behavior part?

Comment: In this case there is only one option that comes in mind: You might have two elements with the id of `custom_container` and only the first one met in DOM tree (the parent) gets replaced first. The second one never gets parsed, because it's removed. Please check.

Comment: Thanks for your input.  I am actually using the wordpress boilerplate and I inserted the ajax jquery function in the same admin script file which already contained another ajax function.
Is this incorrect; should I have created and enqueued the second ajax function in another script file? Or does this not affect it? 
Also there is only one element with this id.